# Oracle, get one row from group and transform into columns

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a process, which at first, in loop, is adding a new person or persons (PERSON_x) into table,
and then updating some data on "wallet" based on new records (PERSON_OPER_X). X is a number identifying
persons and operations which was modyfied in one run/process.

sample data:

```
create table test_tab(
id number(3),
info varchar2(100),
ltime    varchar2(100));

insert into test_tab values(1, 'PERSON_7','1');
insert into test_tab values(2, 'PERSON_7','2');
insert into test_tab values(3, 'PERSON_7','1');
insert into test_tab values(4, 'PERSON_7','2';
insert into test_tab values(5, 'PERSON_7','1');
insert into test_tab values(6, 'PERSON_OPER_7','3;1;4');
insert into test_tab values(8, 'PERSON_10','1');
insert into test_tab values(9, 'PERSON_10','1');
insert into test_tab values(10,'PERSON_10','1');
insert into test_tab values(11,'PERSON_10','1');
insert into test_tab values(12,'PERSON_10','1');
insert into test_tab values(13,'PERSON_OPER_10','5;2;4');
```

SELECT:

```
1   PERSON_7    1
2   PERSON_7    2
3   PERSON_7    1
6   PERSON_OPER_7   3;1;4;
8   PERSON_10   1
9   PERSON_10   1
10  PERSON_10   1
11  PERSON_10   1
12  PERSON_10   1
13  PERSON_OPER_10  5;2;4;
```

Last column is time execution, or list of times, separated by ';'. I want to build a graph/chart to time monitoring in ElasticSearch/Kibana.
What i need right now is to get record where info like 'PERSON_OPER%', get list of times(there will be always 3, and propagate this times through records with the same X. So my output based on this sample data woulg be like:

```
ID  INFO    ADD_PERSON_T    OPER_1_T    OPER_2_T    OPER_3_T
1   PERSON_7    1   3   1   4
2   PERSON_7    2   3   1   4
3   PERSON_7    1   3   1   4
8   PERSON_10   1   5   2   4
9   PERSON_10   1   5   2   4
10  PERSON_10   1   5   2   4
11  PERSON_10   1   5   2   4
12  PERSON_10   1   5   2   4
```

Correct me if i'm wrong, BUT:
since in one run, (f.e. based on INFO=PERSON_7) I add 3 people (in loop) and then i run some calculations (ONE TIME, after loop), then person in id 1,2 and 3 has the same time of calculations.
And on chart this 3 people, or 10 or 100 should have same time in OPER columns, am i wrong?

I got something like this:

```
SELECT  t.*,
        regexp_substr(oper_t,'[[:digit:]]+', 1, 1) AS oper_1_time,
        regexp_substr(oper_t,'[[:digit:]]+', 1, 2) AS oper_2_time
FROM    (
          SELECT t1.*,
                 MAX(CASE when info LIKE '%OPER%' THEN ltime ELSE NULL END) OVER (partition by id_operation) as oper_t
          FROM   (
                  SELECT id,
                         regexp_substr(info, '[A-Z_]+') AS operation,
                         regexp_substr(info, '[0-9]+') AS id_operation,
                         info,
                         ltime
                  FROM   test_tab
                 ) t1
        ) t
WHERE   info not LIKE '%OPER%'
```

but this table could get very big, so query should be very fast, and analytic function here bothering me a little bit.

Anyone has a better idea/approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `self-join` and `row_number` analytical function as following:

```
SELECT ID, INFO, ADD_PERSON_T, OPER_1_T, OPER_2_T, OPER_3_T
FROM
    ( SELECT P.ID, P.INFO, P.LTIME   AS ADD_PERSON_T,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(O.LTIME, '[^;]', 1, 1) AS OPER_1_T,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(O.LTIME, '[^;]', 1, 2) AS OPER_2_T,
            REGEXP_SUBSTR(O.LTIME, '[^;]', 1, 3) AS OPER_3_T,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY P.INFO
                ORDER BY P.ID) AS RN
        FROM
            TEST_TAB P
            JOIN TEST_TAB O ON ( P.INFO = REPLACE(O.INFO, 'OPER_', '') )
        WHERE
            P.INFO NOT LIKE '%OPER%'
            AND O.INFO LIKE '%OPER%'
    )
WHERE RN <= OPER_1_T
ORDER BY ID;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=03afc2365749636948449e01a2b1b277)

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you biggest problem is that your concatenated list in the ltime column violates First Normal Form. Which dictates that each value must be atomic.  You may want to try modifying the structure of your table to adhere to normalization standards.  Once you do that, you will have an easier time writing queries to pull the information you are looking for.
In this case,  a separate table which has a row for each execution.  This will also remove the implicit limitation of having each user only able to have at most 50 executions (Less if any execution exceeds 10)

Comment: Yeah, problem is, that this data from insert list, is from log4plsql (Kibana, ElasticSearch etc.) so this is only what i've got